# On MAC system - CocoaPods was not found -- while doing Ionic - Add or Remove phonegap-push-plugin -

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Error: CocoaPods was not found. Please install version 1.0.1 or greater from https://cocoapods.org/

I know this is the solution

```
ionic cordova plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push 
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then you need to sync the cocoapods repo

```
pod setup
```

This may take a while
Finally install push

```
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

**My OS is MAC**

**But it is still not working.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You cannot run CocoaPods as root.**

To install push you must first install cocoapods.

Follow these steps on your terminal in the Ionic project directory.

First remove what you tried to install

```
ionic plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push
```

Next install cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then you need to sync the cocoapods repo

```
pod setup # (run as normal user not as root)
```

This may take a while

Finally install push

```
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

Then change ownership of folders required

```
chmod -R 777 /usr/etc/
```

So basically you come out of `sudo -i` then run as normal osx user